# why is the type of [ ( True , [ ] ) , ( False , [ ['a'] ] ) ] , "[ (Bool , [ [char] ] )]"?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

When i type `:type [(True,[]),(False, [['a']])] , "[(Bool,[[char]])]"` in ghci it outputs `[ (Bool , [ [char] ] )]`. how is it possible that Haskell's type inference is treating an empty list and [[char]] as the same.

Comment: The empty list has type `[] :: [a]`, since the other list is a `[['a']]`, it knows that `a ~ [Char]`.

Comment: It definitely isn't treating an empty list and `[[Char]]` as the same. However, it *is* treating the empty list as a value of type `[[Char]]` -- and why shouldn't it?

Comment: `[]` aka `Empty` is a *kind of* overloaded type constructor just like `Nothing` of `Maybe a`. It can belong to multiple types those carry type variable(s).

Answer (score 8):

Haskell knows that `True` and `False` are `Bool`s, and furthermore we know that all the elements of a list have the same type.

We are thus looking for a type `[(True,[]),(False, [['a']])]`. We see with the element that it is a 2-tuple with as first element a `Bool`, and as second item there is an empty list, so that has type `[] :: [a]` with `a`, at that time, unknown.

Now if we look at the second item, and see `(False, [['a']])`. This is thus a 2-tuple with `False` as first item, and `[['a']]` as second item. The type of `'a'` is `Char`, hence `['a']` has type `[Char]`, and `[['a']]` has type `[[Char]]`. Since the elements of a list should have the same type, we thus derive that the `a` type parameter of the first item, is `a ~ [Char]`, and thus the outer list has type `[(True,[]),(False, [['a']])] :: [(Bool, [[Char]])]`.

Comment: @Rahat Yes, exactly. (This is the meaning of `a ~ [Char]` in the answer -- you can read the `~` as an equality; the language creators only chose `~` instead of `=` because `=` already has so many uses in the syntax.)

Comment: If I said "here are two doors that both have the same kind of thing behind them" and then I opened the second door, showing you a cat, could you tell me what is behind the first door? That is what the compiler is doing here.

Comment: Cheers, I really appreciate your help. Merry Christmas to all.